# SELECT data from multiple tables using max?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have Project and Score tables like this

[image]

How do I query to get this result, to show all ProjectID, ProjectName, and its **newest Score** (latest Date) with the Date:

[image]

I tried:

```
SELECT R.ProjectID, Name, Score, Date
FROM PWINProject, PWINRecord R
WHERE Date = (
  SELECT max(Date)
  FROM PWINRecord
  WHERE ProjectID = R.ProjectID
)
AND PWINProject.ProjectID = R.ProjectID
```

But it only shows me projects with a score, when a project doesn't have a score yet (e.g. #3 - Amazon) it won't show.

Comment: Use proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 25 years!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `left join` instead on an `inner join` (and use a proper join not the non-standard old style join you are using). However it also simplifies the query to use a window function to determine what row to return e.g.

```
declare @PWINProject table (ProjectId int, [Name] varchar(256))

insert into @PWINProject(ProjectId, [Name])
  select 1, 'Database'
  union all select 2, 'Microsoft'
  union all select 3, 'Amazon'
  union all select 4, 'IBM'

declare @PWINRecord table (ScoreId int, ProjectId int, Score int, [Date] datetime)

insert into @PWINRecord (ScoreId, ProjectId, Score, [Date])
  select 1, 1, 100, '2019-01-15 19:40:46.723'
  union all select 2, 1, 52, '2019-01-15 20:40:46.723'
  union all select 3, 2, 60, '2019-01-15 21:40:46.723'
  union all select 4, 2, 55, '2019-01-15 22:40:46.723'
  union all select 5, 2, 72, '2019-01-15 23:41:46.723'
  union all select 6, 4, 111, '2019-01-16 10:40:46.723'
  union all select 7, 4, 90, '2019-01-17 12:40:46.723'

select ProjectId, [Name], Score, [Date]
from (
  SELECT P.ProjectID, [Name], Score, [Date]
    , row_number() over (partition by R.ProjectID order by [Date] desc) Row#
  FROM @PWINProject P
  left join @PWINRecord R on R.ProjectID = P.ProjectID
) X
where X.Row# = 1
order by ProjectId
```

Returns:

```
ProjectID   Name        Score   Date
1           Database    52      2019-01-15 20:40:46.723
2           Microsoft   72      2019-01-15 23:41:46.723
3           Amazon      NULL    NULL
4           IBM         90      2019-01-17 12:40:46.723
```

PS: This is the recommended style for posting an SQL question, where you setup the data into temp tables or table variables yourself - saves people answering a lot of time. Data in images is a no-no.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to use `OUTER APPLY`:

```
DECLARE @Project TABLE (ProjectId INT, ProjectName VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @Project
  VALUES (1, 'Database'), (2, 'Microsoft'), (3, 'Amazon'), (4, 'IBM')

DECLARE @Score TABLE(ScoreId INT, ProjectId INT, Score INT, RefDate DATE)
INSERT INTO @Score
  VALUES (1, 1, 100, '2019-01-01'), (2, 2, 200, '2019-02-02'), (4, 4, 400, '2019-04-04')

SELECT 
    P.ProjectId,
    P.ProjectName,
    S.Score,
    S.RefDate
FROM @Project P
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 S.*
    FROM @Score S
    WHERE S.ProjectId = P.ProjectId ORDER BY S.RefDate DESC
) S
```

You need to be careful outer apply is not very efficient but it's clean and easy to understand. Other techniques may work involving `ROW_NUMBER`, you should study a bit the execution plan to see what fits best.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PWINProject](
    [ProjectID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_PWINProject] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [ProjectID] ASC
    ) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PWINRecord](
    [ScoreId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ProjectID] [int] NULL,
    [Score] [int] NULL,
    [Date] [datetime] NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_PWINRecord] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [ScoreId] ASC
    ) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[PWINProject] ON 
INSERT [dbo].[PWINProject] ([ProjectID], [Name]) VALUES (1, N'Database')
INSERT [dbo].[PWINProject] ([ProjectID], [Name]) VALUES (2, N'Microsoft')
INSERT [dbo].[PWINProject] ([ProjectID], [Name]) VALUES (3, N'Amazone')
INSERT [dbo].[PWINProject] ([ProjectID], [Name]) VALUES (4, N'IBM')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[PWINProject] OFF
INSERT [dbo].[PWINRecord] ([ScoreId], [ProjectID], [Score], [Date]) VALUES (1, 1, 100, CAST(N'2019-01-15 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[PWINRecord] ([ScoreId], [ProjectID], [Score], [Date]) VALUES (2, 1, 52, CAST(N'2019-01-15 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[PWINRecord] ([ScoreId], [ProjectID], [Score], [Date]) VALUES (3, 2, 60, CAST(N'2019-01-15 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[PWINRecord] ([ScoreId], [ProjectID], [Score], [Date]) VALUES (4, 2, 55, CAST(N'2019-01-15 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[PWINRecord] ([ScoreId], [ProjectID], [Score], [Date]) VALUES (5, 2, 72, CAST(N'2019-01-15 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[PWINRecord] ([ScoreId], [ProjectID], [Score], [Date]) VALUES (6, 4, 111, CAST(N'2019-01-16 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[PWINRecord] ([ScoreId], [ProjectID], [Score], [Date]) VALUES (7, 4, 90, CAST(N'2019-01-17 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PWINRecord]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_PWINRecord_PWINProject] FOREIGN KEY([ProjectID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[PWINProject] ([ProjectID])
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PWINRecord] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_PWINRecord_PWINProject]
```

-- To select your desired output run the below code

```
    ;WITH CTE
    AS
    (
        SELECT p.ProjectID, p.Name, r.Score, r.[Date], ROW_NUMBER()OVER (PARTITION BY R.ProjectID ORDER BY r.[Date] DESC) RN
        FROM PWINProject p
        full join PWINRecord R on p.ProjectID =r.ProjectID
    )
    SELECT ProjectID, Name, Score, [Date]
    FROM CTE
    WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: Out of interest, how does that differ from my answer?

Comment: you need use CTE table to get desired output. which is given in answer

Comment: You most definitely **do not** need to use a CTE... a sub-query as I have shown will produce exactly the same result, and I would imagine with a very similar execution plan.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is the following:

```
select p.ProjectID, p.ProjectName, s.Score as LatestScore, s.[date]
from Project as p
left outer join Scores as s ON p.ProjectID = s.ProjectID
where (
    s.[date] = (
        select top (1) s2.[date]
        from Scores as s2
        where s2.ProjectID = s.ProjectID
        order by [date] desc
    )
    or s.[date] is null
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select P.ProjectID, P.ProjectName, R.Score, R.Date
from PWINProject P
left outer join PWINRecord R on R.ProjectID = P.ProjectID
and R.Date = (
    select max(R2.Date)
    from PWINRecord R2
    where R2.ProjectID = R.ProjectID
)
```